# Joomla 3.0 Template - Field Param doesn't accept HTML

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla template with custom template fields in my templateDetail.xml.
Now I want to have a field for a footer textarea where HTML (a and br-tags) is allowed. If I save the HTML tags in my textarea, they're removed and not outputted:

```
            <field name="footer" type="textarea" default="Footer Text (HTML)"
                   label="Footer content"
                   description="Content of the footer"
                   filter="html" />
```

What is wrong with the field or is it a Joomla bug?

Answer (score 3):

`type="textarea"` creates a standard HTML textarea, however these by default do now allow HTML markup. It will simply get ignored. What I would suggest you do is is use `type="editor"` which will display the TinyMCE editor (by default) and which allows you to input HTML markup.

I know it's a bit overkill just for a footer, however most template providers don't have this feature and get the content from the Footer module instead. So you could also do that too.

### Update

I've just missed the filter type. Before doing anything, try changing the filter to `filter="raw"` and see what the output is.

Answer (score 0):

The correct filter for keeping HTML is `filter="safehtml"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, neither the "raw" nor the "safehtml" filter prevented turning the html into a text string.

My solutions was to decode the variable with html_entity_decode($myhtml).

So then, in your template's index.php:

```
$params = $app->getTemplate(true)->params;
....
echo html_entity_decode($params->get('footer'));
```